# fill out search on website and screen scrape result in r

Tags: r, web-scraping, screen-scraping, search-form

this is my first post, so if my question is too vague or not clear, please tell me so.
I'm trying to scrape a website with news-articles for a research project. But the link to the modified search on that webpage won't work, because the intranet-authentication will spit out an error.
So my idea was, that I fill out the search form and use the resulting link to scrape the website.
Since my boss likes to work with R, he would like me to write an R-skript to do so, but I have no idea how to and haven't found anything working.

Answer (score 0):

You need two packages: `RCurl` and `XML`.
The `RCurl` package is used for internet browsing. It can access HTML forms with _GET or _PUT arguments. So, with it you can login or fill out the any form.

The output from the server would be in HTML. If you want to grep the links, you can use `XLM` package. I helps to get any data form XML format.

But before start, you have to find out that is the search form in webpage (and that arguments should be used). The Firefox browser could be useful. You need two add-ins: Live HTTP header and Firebug. With those add-ins you can inspect webpage much more easier.

I know that it did not solve you problem, but I could not say any more, since it deepens on particular situation and webpage structure. I believe that the tool I have mentioned is quite enough to achieve that you want.

Bet regards.